# RegEx for Multi-Words Without Numbers and Any Special Characters

Tags: regex, string

I want to match input from user to only single or multiple words. This is to avoid spamming and incorrect input. Suppose I have a string like this:

```
I45 w4nt t0 f1n1sh my_$4pp &s00n*
```

I want to the regex to prune that string correctly to:

```
I want to finish...
```

with a character limit. Please how do I go about this? Thanks

Comment: What have you done?  Show us some code please.  It seems to me that you need some replacement rules as well like 4=a and 1=i and then some spell checking afterward

Comment: This is not, by far, a Regex problem. Best approach IMHO, although naive, would be to have a map of numbers/chars to letters and do a replace on the sentence using this map.

Comment: @Casperah, I don't want a replacement of numbers or special strings but I want the user to be unable to enter these in my input fields. Thank you

Comment: You don't want to process the string just to stop the user. For this you have to create an exhaustiv set of basic rules. For this we can't help you. You have to comes up with a requirement and write the test. For exemple number must have a space before. this will stop people from using "I45" but "I 45"

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you want to validate the text:

This regex seems to be doing what you want:

```
^(?=.{1,50}$)(\w+[,.!?&']?\s?)+$
```

It will accept a word followed by an optional punctuation and an optional space.

The ^(?=.{1,50}$) will control the character limit, here the limit is at least 1 character and max 50 characters
The rest is the validation of the text.

It will accepts things like:
I want to finish.
I am great! How are you?
I don't care

But it does not accept:

I could really #*!$ that guy

WARNING! This is really a too simple way to avoid spamming and the users will pretty fast learn a way to get past it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you’re just thinking of:

```
^[a-zA-Z\s\n]{1,150}$
```

This will match letters, spaces and new line characters between 1 and 150 times (your character count)

I’m assuming that you want no numbers or special characters, however if you want something more complex than this, you may want to look at something other than regex.